# Ubuntu 16.10 not recognising bnx2 network interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, firmware

I have a ProLiant DL360 g7 server that was running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I was trying to update the OpenSSH version, but without wanting, my server got upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10. Since then, I have "lost" my NIC cards as the ifconfig does not show them up.

The first thing that I found in google was that the NIC naming system has changed from eth0 to eno1.

When I do

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 up
```

I get the error:

```
Can't load firmware file “bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw”
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory
```

By doing

```
dmesg | grep bnx2
```

it recognises my 4 interfaces mentioning the old ethX naming and in the end:

```
Can't load firmware file “bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw”
```

Then

```
ip link
```

shows:
my four interfaces with the new naming style: eno1, eno2, enp5s0f0 etc

I have also renamed the main interface in `/etc/network/interfaces` to correspond to eno1.

If i do

```
ifconfig eno1
```

I get what I would expect from ifconfig under normal situation: the right IP assigned in eno1 (i.e. inet, netmask, etc and all counters for packets and errors are 0)

```
locate bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw
```

initially returned 1 path: `/lib/firmware/bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw`.  I copied this file, along with other bnx2 files, to:

```
/lib/firmware/3.2.0-55-generic/bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1a.fw
```

Finally,

```
uname -r shows:
```

3.2.0-55-generic
and

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
```

mentions;
Ubuntu. 16.10, yakkety

I feel quite lost in what options I have. I believe the updated system is not recognising my NIC cards and I do not know what I should do.

Other people give a solution for Red Hat ([bnx2: Can't load firmware file "bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102102/bnx2-cant-load-firmware-file-bnx2-bnx2-mips-09-6-2-1b-fw)) which involves rebuilding the initramfs image in red Hat, but not sure whether this is the direction I should take or how this can be done in Ubuntu. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. I had almost the same exact problem, except our server had a directory of `/lib/firmware/bnx2x` (note the extra "x"). I fixed it by creating 
`mkdir /lib/firmware/bnx2` and then from your [linked solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355157/180291) downloaded the [bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/linux/distributions/0linux/archives_sources/linux-firmware/linux-firmware/bnx2/bnx2-mips-09-6.2.1b.fw) file into there and ran `update-initramfs -u` and rebooted and voila. Note that your error is looking for a filename slightly different, ending in [1a.fw](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102102/bnx2-cant-load-firmware-file-bnx2-bnx2-mips-09-6-2-1b-fw), not 1b.fw.